# How method to be moved out to a separate method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Hai every one,

In this I have Three parameters how to move methodname.Equals('xx') method be moved out to a separate method.

```
 public static String APIMethod(string modulename,string methodname,string postContent )
    {
      string recordId = "1";
    string uri = zohocrmurl + modulename + "/"+methodname+"?";
    /* Append your parameters here */
    postContent = "scope=crmapi";
    postContent = postContent + "&authtoken=0ac32dc177c4918eca902fd290a92f4a";//Give your authtoken
//how to move this and create them as seperate methods
    **if (methodname.Equals("insertRecords") || methodname.Equals("updateRecords"))
    {
    postContent = postContent + "&xmlData="+ HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Your CompanyHannahSmithtesting@testing.com");
    }
    if (methodname.Equals("updateRecords") || methodname.Equals("deleteRecords") || methodname.Equals("getRecordById"))
    {
    postContent = postContent + "&id="+recordId;
    }**
    string result = AccessCRM(uri, postContent);
    return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not rather use a [switch (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The switch statement is a control statement that selects a switch
>   section to execute from a list of candidates.

Answer (score 0):

If the `xxx` parts do not modify `name` and are different every time you could do this:

```
public static string rest(string name, string method,string count)
{
     switch(name.Trim().ToLower())
     {
          case: "insert":
          {
              xxx
              break;
          }
          case: "delete":
          {
              xxx
              break;
          }
          case: "update":
          {
              xxx
              break;
          }

        string result = xxx;
        return result;
    }
```